# Is or-ing together attribute selectors possible?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, attributes

I see that multiple attribute selectors are "and-ed" together for example:

```css
/* Links that start with "https" and end in ".org" */
a[href^="https"][href$=".org"] {
  color: green;
}
```

I there a way to express that I want to match all `<a>`s that have `href` containing one `a`, `b` or `c`?

Comment: If you want to "or", can you simply use commas? `a[href~="a"], a[href~="b"], a[href~="c"]`

Comment: Well, for a bit more specific selectors, that can become cumbersome, or at least long-ish.

Comment: It can, have you considered a preprocessor such as SASS or LESS? You can write nested CSS that's compiled into full selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can target elements with one attribute value OR another in CSS.

Geat's selector list approach with commas `,` is the most straightforward, and also the most browser compatible:

```css
a[href^="https"][href$=".org"][href*="a"],
a[href^="https"][href$=".org"][href*="b"],
a[href^="https"][href$=".org"][href*="c"] {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://a.org">https://a.org</a>
<a href="https://b.org">https://b.org</a>
<a href="https://c.org">https://c.org</a>
<a href="https://d.org">https://d.org</a>
<a href="http://a.org">http://a.org</a>
```

I agree though that this can become cumbersome. Luckily we can use the modern CSS [`:is()` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) to shorten this selector:

```css
a[href^="https"][href$=".org"]:is([href*="a"], [href*="b"], [href*="c"]) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://a.org">https://a.org</a>
<a href="https://b.org">https://b.org</a>
<a href="https://c.org">https://c.org</a>
<a href="https://d.org">https://d.org</a>
<a href="http://a.org">http://a.org</a>
```

This also has the benefit of making the selector list forgiving, where if one selector within `:is()` is invalid, the others will still work - a regular selector list in CSS is actually unforgiving and will break the entire list if one selector breaks!

Also note that both examples above will match A, B, C if they are contained within the protocol, path (*any* part of the URL) i.e.

```css
a[href^="https"][href$=".org"]:is([href*="org"], [href*="http"], [href*="h"]) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://org.org">https://org.org</a>
<a href="https://s.org">https://s.org</a>
<a href="https://x.org">https://x.org</a>
<a href="https://y.org">https://y.org</a>
<a href="http://website.org">http://website.org</a>
```

Unfortunately, [the substring syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings) for attribute selectors in CSS does not currently feature a way to match A OR B in an elegant way like I've illustrated below which I'm sure is what you were hoping for:

```css
a[href^="https"][href$=".org"][href*="a"|"b"|"c"]
```